# Looking for «fairly standard» keyboard with a few extra modifiers

Tags: keyboards

I would be grateful if you could recommend me keyboard that would satisfy the following criteria:

1. it must have a few (there can be more, but I feel quite sure that half a dozen would be absolutely enough for the rest of my life) extra keys compare to standard 104/105 one; I'd like to use those keys as modifiers (like Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Win or, if you prefer, Super);
2. it should be fairly standard; by this I mean that it should work without installing some extremely temperamental and finicky Chinese software that is very hard to download and even harder to get working (let alone the fact it may have no English version at all); clearly, some extra software, drivers or something will most probably be necessary, but it should be... well, fairly standard.
3. it should work with Windows (Windows 10 to be precise); also, I regularly work on Linux machine to which I connect remotely, so it is highly desirable those extra modifiers could be used through RDP (I do not mind tinkering to get them working in Linux, but there should be such a possibility at least in principle); I don't own a Mac and do not plan to own one, so keyboards optimised for Macs are of no interest for me.
4. it should be not very expensive (while I would probably be very happy with [this modern reincarnation](https://mechboards.co.uk/products/hyper-7-v4) of the legendary Space cadet keyboard, I am not that rich to allow myself to buy a piece for 360 Euro; something like 150 Euro is affordable for me, though);
5. I rely heavily on AHK in my daily routine work, so it should be possible to use AHK to assign shortcuts with those extra modifiers (absence of this possibility will ruin the whole enterprise).

I suppose it could be a keyboard designed for gamers (I am not very much into gaming, so I really do not know much about such keyboards).

I do not think I would be happy with external keypads. This idea sounds not bad in theory, but according to my experience the time spent to move your hand between the keyboard and anything else (save mouse and cup of tea/coffee here for those are sacred items) is the time lost forever.

P. S. I probably want too much, I know. Still, I'll be grateful for ideas, opinions and advices.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how an external keypad is any worse than a keyboard with more buttons (besides the extra cable): if you put it on the left of your keyboard, it's no different than a larger keyboard.